# how to visualize the sensor data!

Tags: c++, pcl

now I am making the node for my custom lidar.
the struct of this lidar pointcloud is

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct spherical {
    uint32_t        timestamp;
    float   intensity;
    float   threshold;
    float   theta;        // vertical
    float   pie;          // horizontal
    float   radius;       // depth
    float   speed;        // speed vector with current angle
    uint32_t        frame_cnt;    // Frame counter
}cspherical_t; 
#pragma pack(pop)
```

---

and this one, and the code that I made to visualize is this code

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include "VicsenLidar.h"
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

ros::Publisher pointcloud_pub;
ros::Publisher speed_pub;

// Define your callback function to process the Lidar data
void lidarframe_callback(const cspherical_t* points, size_t point_num)
{
    // Add ROS_INFO statements for debugging
    ROS_INFO("Lidar callback called with %zu points.", point_num);

    // Create a PointCloud2 message
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 pointcloud_msg;

    // Fill in the header of the PointCloud2 message
    pointcloud_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    pointcloud_msg.header.frame_id = "fmcw"; // Adjust the frame_id as needed

    // Create a PCL PointCloud to hold the data
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> pcl_cloud;

    // Fill the PCL PointCloud with data from your Lidar callback
    for (size_t i = 0; i < point_num; i++) {
        pcl::PointXYZI point;
        float x = points[i].radius * sin(points[i].theta) * cos(points[i].pie);
        float y = points[i].radius * sin(points[i].theta) * sin(points[i].pie);
        float z = points[i].radius * cos(points[i].theta);

        point.x = x;
        point.y = y;
        point.z = z;
        
        point.intensity = points[i].intensity/100000;

        pcl_cloud.push_back(point);

        // 포인트 정보 출력
         ROS_INFO("Point %zu: x=%.2f, y=%.2f, z=%.2f, intensity=%.2f, speed=%.2f", i , point.x, point.y, point.z, point.intensity, points[i].speed);
}
    

    // Convert PCL PointCloud to PointCloud2
    pcl::toROSMsg(pcl_cloud, pointcloud_msg);

    // Publish the PointCloud2 message on the "fmcw_pointcloud" topic
    pointcloud_pub.publish(pointcloud_msg);

    // Extract and publish speed values separately
    for (size_t i = 0; i < point_num; i++) {
        float speed = points[i].speed; // Extract speed value from packed data

        // Create a message for speed and publish it separately
        std_msgs::Float32 speed_msg;
        speed_msg.data = speed;
        speed_pub.publish(speed_msg);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Initialize ROS
    ros::init(argc, argv, "fmcw_lidar_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    // Create a publisher for the PointCloud2 data
    pointcloud_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("fmcw_pointcloud", 100);

    // Create a publisher for the speed data
    speed_pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Float32>("lidar_speed", 100);

    // Initialize the Vicsen Lidar
    vicsen_init();

    /* 연결된 Vicsen Lidar를 찾습니다. 만약 라이다를 찾지 못하면 프로그램을 종료합니다. */
    const char** ip_lists = vicsen_find();

    if (!ip_lists) {
        std::cout << "Vicsen Lidar를 찾을 수 없습니다!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // IPv4 주소만 사용
    for (size_t i = 0; ip_lists[i] != NULL; i++) {
        // IPv4 주소인지 확인하려면 문자열로 변환하고 첫 번째 바이트를 확인합니다.
        std::string ip_string(ip_lists[i]);
        if (ip_string.find(".") != std::string::npos) { // 문자열에 '.'이 있으면 IPv4 주소로 간주
            std::cout << "Vicsen IP (IPv4): " << ip_lists[i] << std::endl;
            /* IPv4 주소를 사용하여 Vicsen Lidar와 통신 또는 다른 작업을 수행하세요. */
        }
    }

    /* Vicsen Lidar에 연결하여 제어 및 센서 데이터 수집합니다. */
    vicsen_connect(ip_lists[0]);

    /* 센서 데이터를 수신할 때 호출할 콜백 함수를 등록합니다. */
    set_frame_callback(lidarframe_callback);

    /* Vicsen Lidar 내부 FPGA의 온도를 얻습니다. */
    float fpga_temp = get_fpga_temperature();

    /* Vicsen Lidar 내 레이저 다이오드(LD)의 온도를 얻습니다. */
    float ld_temp = get_ld_temperature();

    /* Vicsen Lidar 장치의 시리얼 번호를 얻습니다. */

    /* Vicsen Lidar 내 스캐너를 제어합니다. Preset: 0, framerate: 3.
     * preset에 대한 정보는 사용자 매뉴얼을 참조하시면 좋을 것 같습니다. 
     */
    set_scanner_preset(0, 3);

    /* 설정된 preset 및 framerate 정보를 얻습니다. */
    uint8_t scanner_preset = get_scanner_preset();
    float scanner_framerate = get_scanner_framerate();

    /* Vicsen Lidar가 감지할 수 있는 최대 속도를 설정합니다. */
    set_speed_limit(3);
    /* 설정된 최대 속도 제한을 얻습니다. */
    float speed_limit = get_speed_limit();

    /* Vicsen Lidar가 감지할 수 있는 점의 민감도를 설정합니다.
     * 점 감지 민감도에 대한 정보는 사용자 매뉴얼을 참조하십시오.
     */
    set_threshold_value(3);
    /* 점 감지 민감도를 얻습니다. */
    uint8_t threshold_value = get_threshold_value();

    /* 감지된 점 정보를 통신할 포트를 설정합니다.
     * 이 포트 설정은 SDK의 UDP 서버와 Vicsen Lidar의 대상 포트 모두 변경합니다.
     */
    set_udp_port(33232);
    /* Vicsen Lidar에서 사용 중인 포트 정보를 얻습니다. */
    uint16_t port = get_udp_port();

    /* 감지된 점 정보를 통신할 IP 주소를 설정합니다. */
    set_udp_ipaddress("192.168.0.18");
    /* Vicsen Lidar에서 사용 중인 IP 주소 정보를 얻습니다. */
    const char* udp_ip = get_udp_ipaddress();

    /* Vicsen Lidar와의 통신으로 얻은 정보를 표시합니다. */
    std::cout << "FPGA temperature: " << fpga_temp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "LD temperature: " << ld_temp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Scanner preset: " << (int)scanner_preset << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Scanner framerate: " << scanner_framerate << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Speed limit: " << speed_limit << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Point threshold: " << (int)threshold_value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UDP port: " << (int)port << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UDP IP: " << udp_ip << std::endl;

    // ROS Timer를 사용하여 주기적으로 메시지를 발행
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10); // 10hz로 설정, 0.1 초에 한번 publish.

    while (ros::ok())
    {
        ros::spinOnce(); // 노드 이벤트 루프 처리

        /* Vicsen Lidar와의 통신으로 정보를 주기적으로 업데이트 */
        fpga_temp = get_fpga_temperature();
        ld_temp = get_ld_temperature();
        scanner_preset = get_scanner_preset();
        scanner_framerate = get_scanner_framerate();
        speed_limit = get_speed_limit();
        threshold_value = get_threshold_value();
        port = get_udp_port();
        udp_ip = get_udp_ipaddress();

        /* Vicsen Lidar와의 통신으로 얻은 정보를 실시간으로 출력 */
        std::cout << "FPGA temperature: " << fpga_temp << std::endl;
        std::cout << "LD temperature: " << ld_temp << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Scanner preset: " << (int)scanner_preset << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Scanner framerate: " << scanner_framerate << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Speed limit: " << speed_limit << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Point threshold: " << (int)threshold_value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "UDP port: " << (int)port << std::endl;
        std::cout << "UDP IP: " << udp_ip << std::endl;

        loop_rate.sleep(); // 주기적으로 루프 실행
    }

    // Deinitialize the Vicsen Lidar
    vicsen_deinit();

    return 0;
}
```

---

and this is a error that I got when I use
rosrun rviz rviz -f fmcw
and adding the extra pointcloud2, with the frame "fmcw"

````
WARN] [1697793848.886709774]: Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty

```
````

Answer (score 0):

You will not get this error if you change your fixed frame to "fmcw" in RVIZ or if you broadcast a tf between your fixed frame (it is empty now and this is the error you get) and fmcw. If the lidar is 2D, I think it would be better to use the "sensor_msgs/LaserScan" message datatype.

Comment: Umm sadly I did all thing but it happened I am not sure..

Comment: If you are okay is there any custum code to get the sensor data and visualize pointcloud2